# Find days where no records exists in current month

Tags: mysql

I have a table with username, and date of presence for each day

```
user1 - 2017-02-01
user1 - 2017-02-02
user1 - 2017-02-04
user1 - 2017-02-05
user1 - 2017-02-07

user2 - 2017-02-01
user2 - 2017-02-03
user2 - 2017-02-04
user2 - 2017-02-05
user2 - 2017-02-07
```

I need a query in mysql that can result the Missed Days of users

output should be

```
user1 - 3,6 
user2 - 2,6
```

Comment: "a table"?  what is its name?  do you also have a user table that has all the usernames you are interested in?  do you have some other table that contains all the dates you are interested in?

Comment: What about '8'?

Comment: assume table name as "attendance"